# How to create MongoDB full text index with Arabic language support

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

Trying to enable full text search in MongoDB. It is working with default language English but not with Arabic.

Ihave tried this:

```
db.Tracks.ensureIndex({ 
  "Name": "text", 
  "About": "text"
}, { 
  "name": "tracks_full_text", 
  "default_language": "ara",
  "language_override": "ara" 
});
```

But this shows message like bellow

```
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "default_language is not valid",
        "code" : 67,
        "codeName" : "CannotCreateIndex"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MongoDB Arabic language currently not supported. A list of supported languages can be found here` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/text-search-languages/

You can still use `$regex` operator instead (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) But it's slower than `$text` indexes.

P.S I'm currently creating a search function for the Armenian language. Probably will use elastic search integration.

Comment: It seems that version 3.2 supports Arabic language (https://docs.huihoo.com/mongodb/3.4/reference/text-search-languages/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I set the language to `none` and it worked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33732802)